# Tooltip does not display when anchor is out of normal flow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my site, I use DOM nodes of class="trigger" as anchors for tooltips. When the mouve hovers these anchors, a tooltip displays. The jQuery code generating the tooltip container is as follows:

```
$('.trigger').mouseover(function() // OnMouseOver event
{
    $("<div/>", {
        id: "tooltip",
        css: {
            display: "none",
            position: "absolute",
            border: "3px solid #111",
            color: "#000",
            padding: "5px",
            opacity: 1.0,
            fontSize: "15pt",
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            borderRadius: "15px",
            zIndex: 3000
        }
    }).appendTo(this);

    $("#tooltip").html($(this).attr('title'));
    $(this).attr('title',''); // empty the title attribute of the anchor (avoiding default browser reaction)
    $('#tooltip').show(); // show the tooltip
}).mousemove(function(e) // OnMouse mode event
{
    $('#tooltip').css('top', e.pageY + 20); // tooltip 20px below mouse poiunter
    $('#tooltip').css('left', e.pageX - 20);    // tooltip with mouse pointer   
}).mouseout(function() // OnMouseOut event
{
    $(this).attr('title',$('#tooltip').html()); // set the title back to initial value
    $(this).children('div#tooltip').remove();   // get rid of the tooltip container 
});
```

It works very well when the anchor is positioned in the normal flow of the page but it does not display when the anchor is out of the flow as in

```
$("<img/>", {
    id: "arrowup",
    class: "trigger noprint",
    css:{
        display:"none",
        position:"fixed",
        bottom:'15px',
        right:'10px',
        cursor: "pointer"
    },
    src:"../images/arrowup.jpe",
    alt:"vers le haut",
    title: "Haut de la page",
    click:function(){
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: "0px"}, 800);
        return false;                       
        }
    }).appendTo("body");
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    var obj = $("#arrowup");

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300){ 
        obj.fadeIn(800);
    } else { 
        obj.fadeOut(800);
    }
});
```

Is this normal behaviour or is there a trick to get the tooltip displayed normally?

Comment: In the second code snippet you have no `.show()` method ;)

Comment: In fact, the code that follows should have been appended. As you can see, it shows but only when the page is scrolled.

Comment: can you add a fiddle?

Comment: you really shouldn't have so much CSS in your JS code, it would be better to have those styles in your stylesheet, why not tie them to #tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my site, I use DOM nodes of class="trigger" as anchors for tooltips. When the mouve hovers these anchors, a tooltip displays and moves with the mouse motion. The jQuery code generating the tooltip container was modified as follows:

```
$("#template").on("mouseover", ".trigger", function(){ // OnMouseOver event

    $("<div/>", {
        id: "tooltip",
        css: {
            display: "block",
            position: "absolute",
            border: "3px solid #111",
            color: "#000",
            padding: "5px",
            opacity: 1.0,
            fontSize: "15pt",
            title: "XXX",
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            borderRadius: "15px",
            zIndex: 3000
        }
    }).appendTo("body");

    $("#tooltip").html($(this).attr('title'));
    $(this).attr('title',''); // empty the title attribute of the anchor (avoiding default browser reaction)
    $('#tooltip').show(); // show the tooltip
}).on("mousemove", ".trigger", function(e){ // OnMouse mode event
    $('#tooltip').css('top', e.pageY + 20); // tooltip 20px below mouse poiunter
    $('#tooltip').css('left', e.pageX - 20);    // tooltip with mouse pointer   
}).on("mouseout", ".trigger", function(){ // OnMouseOut event
    $(this).attr('title',$('#tooltip').html()); // set the title back to initial value
    $("body").children('div#tooltip').remove(); // get rid of the tooltip container 
});
```

Following Edward's suggestion, all  $(".trigger").event(function() {...}); were replaced by $("#parent).on("event", ".trigger", function() {...}); so that jQuery would be aware of content added dynamically to the DOM after DOM ready. This new content is generated as follows:

```
    $("<div/>", { // creates a container <div> for the arrowup image
    id: "arrowup",
    class:"trigger no_underline", // is an anchor for tooltip
    css:{
        display:"none",
        position:"fixed",
        bottom:"30px",
        right:"30px",
        cursor: "pointer"
    },
    click:function(){ // assign page up functionality
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: "0px"}, 800);
        return false;                       
        },
    title: "Haut de page" // title to be passed to the tooltip
    }).appendTo("#template");

$("<img/>", { // creates the image and its functionality 
    src:"../images/arrowup.jpe",
    alt:"vers le haut",
    }).appendTo("#arrowup");

$(window).bind("scroll", function() { // shows tooltip only when page is scrolled
    var obj = $("#arrowup");
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300){ 
        obj.fadeIn(800);
    } else { 
        obj.fadeOut(800);
    }
});
```

In the original listings, each of the .trigger have been individually given instructions. If new .trigger are created, they won't have heard the instruction and won't respond to mouseover, mousemove and mouseout events, each of them being directly responsible for their own events. In the modified setting, only the container (here #template) has been given the instruction; it is responsible for noticing the events on behalf of its child elements. The work of catching events has been delegated.

Referring to Alexander's comment, in my question I was binding to the anchor position whereas I am now binding to the position of cursor at the time of tooltip firing: this is the behaviour that I expected.
3

When I asked the question, I believed that the non-show of the tooltip was related to the fact the the new element was out of the normal flow (position: fixed). It is not that at all.

Everything works as expected now! Thanks to all who helped me.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right, you need to wrap your image with fixed `div`:

```html
<div class="fixed">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <div class="tooltip">Tooltip</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```css
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}

.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
}

.fixed:hover .tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

### Check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j66Yr/1/)

Hover over placeholder to see tooltip.

Comment: I used the solution offered by Alexander and it works. The tooltip shows. However, it is a CSS solution, not à jQuery solution.

Comment: Ok, i'll add full solution tommorow

Answer (score 0):

When you add content dynamically to the page after dom load you need to let javascript know you have done so.

This is done by event propagation. If your triggers are contained within a parent div do this:

```
$('#parent').on('mouseover', '.trigger', function() {

//your code here.

});
```

Comment: The code shown in my question is flawed. It tries to give an <img> a child <div>. Corrected! 2 new elements on the fly. Need to use your suggestion. I do it. Strange results! Click on various triggers and on the second or third trial, the content of the tooltip diseappear. $(this) does not execute properly. It is very confusing! Who is $(this)?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works!

```
$('.trigger').mouseover(function(){ // OnMouseOver event
    $("<div/>", {
        id: "tooltip",
        css: {
            display: "block",
            position: "absolute",
            border: "3px solid #111",
            color: "#000",
            padding: "5px",
            opacity: 1.0,
            fontSize: "15pt",
            title: "XXX",
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            borderRadius: "15px",
            zIndex: 3000
        }
    }).appendTo("body");

    $("#tooltip").html($(this).attr('title'));
    $(this).attr('title',''); // empty the title attribute of the anchor (avoiding default browser reaction)
    $('#tooltip').show(); // show the tooltip
}).mousemove(function(e) // OnMouse mode event
{
    $('#tooltip').css('top', e.pageY + 20); // tooltip 20px below mouse poiunter
    $('#tooltip').css('left', e.pageX - 20);    // tooltip with mouse pointer   
}).mouseout(function() // OnMouseOut event
{
    $(this).attr('title',$('#tooltip').html()); // set the title back to initial value
    $("body").children('div#tooltip').remove(); // get rid of the tooltip container 
});
```

and note that the only modification made to it is that the div#tooltip is now located in the body rather than as a child of its anchor.

Why does this make it work? I really don't know.

Comment: You've implemented different behavior:
1. in your question you are binding to the anchor position;
2. in your answer you are binding to the position of cursor at the time of tooltip firing.

Do you still need example code with first behavior implemented?

Comment: In my question, jQuery creates img#arrowup.trigger dynamically. The mouseover event on .trigger creates div#tooltip dynamically and append it to img#arrowup, an empty tag that cannot have any content (except the image itself). Can this be the real reason why the tooltip does not show?

Comment: Yes, this is real reason. Check previous jsfiddle with appending `div` to the `img`: http://jsfiddle.net/j66Yr/2/